# Is this the proper way to add a 'class' attribute to a form date element

Tags: forms, 8, datetime

```
$form['stop_date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('Stop Date'),
  '#default_value' => date("Y-m-d"), // default to today 
  '#id' => 'stop_date', 
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('dateSel-Fld')), 
  '#required' => true,
);
```

When using the #attribute property the form is not being rendered successfully.

Comment: I think I had something like that before. Alternatively you could try to add your class with a wrapper via `'#prefix' => '<div class="foo">', '#suffix' => '</div>',` or nest your form element one level deeper with some `'#type' => 'container',` as parent.

Comment: Make sure to use the new array formatting when dealing with Drupal 8 too, so `[]` rather than `array()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8, you can try this if you want to add certain attributes to the views filter (in my case, it is a select dropdown)

Add this to your mymodule.theme file

```
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      $form['field_month_target_id']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'GAEventTrack';
      $form['field_month_target_id']['#attributes']['eventcategory'] = 'Category';
      $form['field_month_target_id']['#attributes']['eventaction'] = 'Action';
      $form['field_month_target_id']['#attributes']['eventlabel'] = 'Label';
    }
```

Of course you can add a checking to fit your needs =)

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

Here's the references:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes

And a usage example:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/7

Comment: Japo, thanks for the response.  However, my issue resides in Drupal 8.  I'm beginning to suspect there is a bug in core.